# Easiest way to add scrolling to a mac application

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, scroll

Is there an easy way to add scrolling to the contents of a NSwindow? as an example scrolling sideways on this window to reveal more space?

[image: The window]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very easy using an `NSScrollView`. In Interface Builder just drag a scroll view into your window. Then you can embed whatever contents you want in the `NSScrollView`'s view. In Interface Builder's Attributes Inspector of the scroll view you can set whether you want horizontal and/or vertical scroll bars.